# Как адаптировать в CSS так же?

Tags: css, вёрстка, jsx

На странице регистрации Facebook `https://ru-ru.facebook.com/` я заметил, что под кнопками и полями ввода имеется белый квадрат. Когда я изменяю разрешение экрана через DevTools, этот квадрат и все элементы над ним изменяются вместе, как будто "приклеены". Каким способом можно достичь такого же результата через css? Понятно, что используется media. Я пробовал повторить эффект, но не получается заставить прямоугольник (в моем случае) двигаться вместе с кнопками в нем, при этом чтобы кнопки держали одинаковое расстояние от краев прямоугольника.
Заранее спасибо за помощь

jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './RegistrationForms.css';

const RegistrationForms = () => {
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState(false);
  const [WhichForm, setWhichForm] = useState(true);

  const toggleForm = (isLogin) => {
    setShowForm(true);
    setWhichForm(isLogin);
  };

  return (
    <div className="registration-form">



      <div className="Logo">
        <img src="/logo/WML.svg" alt="Логотип" />
      </div>

    <div className="Slogan">
      <p>Просто надпись</p>
    </div>



      {/* Вставка изображения на заднем фоне */}
      <div className="image-background">
        <img src="/img/Just.jpg" alt="Фон" />
      </div>

      <div className="registration-overlay"></div>



      {/* Отображение кнопок "Войти" и "Зарегистрироваться" */}
      {!showForm && (
        <div className="login-buttons">
          {/* Вызов функции toggleForm с параметром true (для входа) при клике на кнопку */}
          <button className="login-button" onClick={() => toggleForm(true)}>Войти</button>
          {/* Вызов функции toggleForm с параметром false (для регистрации) при клике на кнопку */}
          <button className="register-button" onClick={() => toggleForm(false)}>Зарегистрироваться</button>
        </div>
      )}

    </div>
  );
};

export default RegistrationForms;
```

css:

```
.registration-form {
    position: relative; /* Относительное позиционирование для размещения форм над видео */
    height: 100vh; /* Минимальная высота контейнера, чтобы видео занимало весь экран */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Центрируем контейнер по горизонтали */
    max-width: 1280px;
  }
  

  /* Стили для заднего фото */
  .image-background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden; /* Предотвращаем прокручивание контейнера */
  }
  
  .image-background img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center; /* Чтобы изображение было центрировано */
  }
  
  /* Убрать отступы по умолчанию */
  body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }


.Logo{
  position: relative;
  height: 3%;
  width: 3%;
  top: 7%;
  left: -7%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.Slogan{
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  top: 37%;
  left: 10%;
  font-size: 2vw;
}


/* Стили для контейнера с кнопками */
.login-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  width: 17vw;
  height: 50vh;
  top: calc(40% - (0vh / 2));
  left: calc(65.8% - (2vw / 2));
  z-index: 3; 
}

  
  /* Стили для кнопок */
  .login-button {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff; /* Белый цвет текста */
    width: 100%;
    height: 11.5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .register-button {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 11.5%;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }



  .registration-overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 19.5vw;
    height: 20vh;
    top: calc(29.5% - (0vh / 2));
    left: calc(76% - (2vw / 2));
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  }














/* Очень маленькие экраны (портретная ориентация): ширина до 360px */
@media (orientation: portrait) and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 460px) {

  .Logo{
    position: relative;
    width: 7%;
    height: 7%;
    top: 4%;
    left: 12%;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  
  .Slogan{
    color: white;
    top: -7%;
    left: 24%;
    font-size: 5vw;
    width: 80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }



  .login-buttons {
    position: relative;
    width: 65vw;
    height: calc(20vw + 6vh);
    top: calc(20% - (calc(20vw + 29vh) / 2));
    left: calc(50% - (65vw / 2));
    font-size: 2.5vh;
  }

  .login-button {
    width: 54vw;
    height: 8vh;
    border-radius: 11px;
  }

  .register-button {
    width: 54vw;
    height: 8vh;
    border-radius: 11px;
  }

  .registration-overlay {
    position: relative;
    width: 64vw;
    height: calc(20vw + 11vh);
    top: calc(38.3% - (11vh / 2));
    left: calc(62% - (25vw / 2));
  }
}
```

Comment: О каком белом квадрате речь? Там же самая стандартная карточка

Comment: Что за карточка? Я так понял у них имеется фон, на нем квадрат-контейнер, на котором расположились кнопки и формы. Через адаптацию они заставили их адаптироваться вместе, не теряя структуру и сохраняя пропорциональные размеры. Вот мне и нужно узнать, как добиться такого эффекта, при котором "карточка" и кнопки с формами держатся неразрывно. Я привел свой код, однако я не смог повторить: кнопки и прямоугольник (в моем случае) разъезжаются.

Comment: Вам devtools отключили что ли?) Обычная карточка (`div` со стилями), обычная форма: https://i.imgur.com/bmO2m4r.png Не изобретайте велосипед с костылями, к тому же, facebook - это один из худших примеров, на котором стоит разбирать верстку

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!) А я то думал, что они идеально подобрали размеры для адаптации контейнеру и формам или использовали flexbox) Подскажите пожалуйста, почему facebook - это один из худших примеров, на котором стоит разбирать верстку?

Comment: @Dream, скорее всего из-за того, что делался давно, много чего удалялось\внедрялось и вообще в целом сделан не по канонам, но это не точно.